# Item in the ArrayList gets replaced instead of appending

Tags: java, android, arraylist, sharedpreferences, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to bring all the items from the ArrayList getting saved in EditActivity to the MainActivity using SharedPreferences. But only the last entered data gets displayed in the ListView on the first MainActivity. How can I make all the text entered into the EditText get displayed as a different item in the ListView and not replace the earlier item.
Here is my Code:

> MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ListView list;
private Button nextButton;

ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    nextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextButton);

        loadData();

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            nextActivity();
        }
    });
}
public void nextActivity(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, EditActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void loadData(){
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("Data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = sp.getString("list", null);
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {}.getType();
    arrayList = gson.fromJson(json, type);

    if(arrayList == null){
        arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
}}
```

> EditActivity

```
public class EditActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText input;
private Button addButton;

public ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
public ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit);

    input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
    addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addButton);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String getInput = input.getText().toString();
            adapter.addAll(getInput);
            saveData();
            input.setText(""); //clear the value in the edit text
        }
    });

}
public void saveData(){
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("Data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(list);
    editor.putString("list", json);
    editor.apply();
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forget to add item to list before save and thus the result is you are saving only the last item.

```
addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String getInput = input.getText().toString();
        list.add(getInput); //add this line
        adapter.addAll(getInput);
        saveData();
        input.setText(""); //clear the value in the edit text
    }
});
```